# Is the value of probability invariant of function of a random variable

Tags: probability

Consider two random variables following a common distribution F. Is $P(X_{1} > X_{2}) = P(f(X_{1})>f(X_{2}))$ for any function f?

Comment: If $f $ was a constant function then the right hand side would be zero.

Comment: Take f(x) = -x for an obvious counterexample.

Comment: You need to make assumptions about f in order for this to be true. Assuming that f is strictly monotonic and increasing should do it

Answer (score 6):

Let $X_1, X_2$ be two independent random variables each with pmf

$$ P_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{2} & x =1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & x =-1 \\
\end{cases} $$

Then $\mathsf P(X_1>X_2)=0.25$ but $\mathsf P\big(X_1^2>X_2^2\big)=0$

Answer (score 5):

**No.  That equation does not hold in general.**  Although that equation does not hold in general, it does hold for monotonically increasing functions.  If $f$ is monotone increasing (e.g., exponential or logarithmic functions) then you have the event equivalence:

$$\{ X > Y \} \quad \quad \iff \quad \quad \{ f(X) > f(Y) \}.$$

In this case the underlying events are equivalent and so the probability equation you give holds regardless of the distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$.  Note also that there are some special combinations of a distribution $F$ and a function $f$ for which your probability equation holds, but it will not hold as a general property unless $f$ is a monotonically increasing function.

Comment: Might want to add the qualifier "strictly" to "monotonic". "monotonic" is often used to refer to functions with $x > y \rightarrow f(x) \ge f(y)$ rather than $x > y \rightarrow f(x) > f(y)$

Comment: Maybe.  But for non-strict version I would usually say "monotone non-decreasing" rather than "monotone increasing".  I would generally take "increasing" to imply strictness, unless the contrary is stipulated.  Rather than change it, I think I'll just leave these comments here for the OP to see.

Comment: Wikipedia says "[A function is called monotonically increasing (also increasing or non-decreasing), if for all x and y such that  $x\leq y$  one has$f(x) \leq f(y)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)"

Comment: That's all very well, but I've seen the alternative terminology elsewhere, and it makes more sense.  By the terminology you have linked to, the constant function $f(x)=c$ is an "increasing" function, yet it never increases.  It is also a "decreasing" function, yet it never decreases.  Curious terminology, no?

Answer (score 0):

A simple counterexample for any $X_i$ with $P(X_i > 0) = 1$ is the function $f(x) = x^{-1}$. It reverses inequalities, hence $P(f(X_1) > f(X_2)) = P(X_1 < X_2)$, which is in general different from $P(X_1 > X_2)$.